# Access the Winform control that started a thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, winforms, user-controls, c++-cli

I've got a WinForm project which uses a `PageControl` and `PageTabs`. Say there are two `PageTabs`, each with their own `UserControl` object. If one `UserControl` starts a Thread() which is meant to loop endlessly and access a `TextBox` on the `UserControl` that started it, how does that thread's process access the correct `UserControl`.

More specifically:

The `GUI.h` has two `PageTabs`, each with their own `UserControl` object.

[image]

The first tab has a `ReceiveButton` which starts a thread. That thread does a lot of work on a loop and updates the `TextBox`.

[image]

The second tab is essentially the same, but has it's own `ReceiveButton` and `TextBox`. This button also starts a thread and is supposed to update *this* `TextBox`.

I'm having a tough time figuring out how to make each thread access/update it's own respective `TextBox`.

---

Here's sort of the chain of code my `UserControl` follows:

```
//MyUserControl.h
void ContinueNormally(void);

System::Void buttonReceive_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e)
        {
            this->myThread = gcnew System::Threading::Thread(gcnew System::Threading::ThreadStart(this, &MyUserControl::ContinueNormally));
            this->myThread->Start();
        }
```

---

```
//GUI.h
#include "MyUserControl.h"

void BufferRecieveLoop()
{
    while (true)
    {
        //receive from multicast    

        incoming.Process(buffer, bytes_read, endian); //this is the method in the other .h file
    }
}


void MyUserControl::ContinueNormally()
{
    //setup

    BufferRecieveLoop();

    //cleanup
}
```

---

```
//EntityStateProcessorPdu.h
#include "MyUserControl.h"

void EntityStatePduProcessor::Process(const DIS::Pdu& packet)
{
    //do stuff

    ///Below are attempts at accessing the correct textbox, all in vain :(
    //GUI_Example_Receive::Globals::gui->SetConsoleTextBoxText(sysStr);
    //GUI_Example_Receive::Globals::gui->Controls->Find("myUserControl", true)[0]->Controls->Find("")
    //GUI_Example_Receive::MyUserControl::SetTextBoxConsoleText(sysStr);
}
```

---

I should also note that this works just fine with one UserControl, or one PageTab. I'm `Invoking` correctly to get the UI thread to do the updating.

Answer (score 0):

In Win32 (and pretty much any OS GUI that I know of) only allows one "thread" to access the GUI.  This is normally known as the "GUI Thread".

The "GUI Thread" is the thread that runs the Win32 [message pump](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_loop_in_Microsoft_Windows).

Normally what you do is post your own "custom" messages that will be run in the GUI thread and you update your GUI controls from there.

I don't know the C++ GUI library you are using but it will most likely provide some sort of utility for post messages or code to be run on the GUI thread.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows Forms every controls has a method Invoke, that it does what you search:
calls a delegate in the same thread that creates the control.